# Where can I find a picture or physical description of the A3 scramble telephone system?

Tags: world-war-two, technology, communication, churchill, secrecy

Who has a picture or physical description of the A3 scramble telephone system, which was used for speech privacy by Roosevelt and Churchill between 1940 and 1943. The system was most likely located near the international switchboard in the AT&T building at 27 Walker Street in New York.
There seems to be no pictures left of the A3 except for a photo in the New York Times in 1940. This in sharp contrast to the first digital telephone system SIGSALY of which many photos exist.
I understood that the archives of AT&T had to turn over all material on the A3 to the US authorities when the war ended.

Comment: I think the document is actually titled "History of speech privacy systems-1970" and apparently the AT&T Archives and History Center has (or at least had) a copy.

Comment: @Chuck - site convention is that the question should contain everything you know/ all the research you have done. We discourage OP from adding comments.  I've moved your comment into the question.  Please validate that my edit helped, then flag comments for deletion where they are no longer needed.  The longer the comment string, the less likely you are to get a satisfactory answer.  (and welcome to the site and thank you for a couple of good questoins)

Comment: I presume you have found http://chris-intel-corner.blogspot.com/2012/02/intercepted-conversations-bell-labs-3.html - further, the report (inter-departmental memorandum?) appears to be by a D. Mitchell, who may also be linked to the first AT&T mobile phone deployment in 1946.

Comment: Frustratingly, https://blog.sciencemuseum.org.uk/scrambled-phones/ does not have an A3 picture

Comment: I think we can rule out your West Street guess for the location, in favor of  Walker Street: I have talked with Bell Labs old timers, and the division of work was such that operational systems in commercial service were run by Long Lines on their own premises, not Bell Labs on theirs.

Comment: And: I doubt the 47 Walker Street address, and think the correct address is 24 Walker Street, which is described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32_Avenue_of_the_Americas , and named in https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5055548 .  The 47 address is a small building, described in https://streeteasy.com/building/47-walker-street-new_york, unlikely to be used for such a purpose by AT&T.

Comment: @ Jon, yes I found the Chris blogspot. Great info, very accurate. Thanks

Comment: I think a more accurate reference for the missing document is "Mitchell, D. "Notes on the History of speech Privacy Systems." Bell Telephone Laboratories. InterDepartmental Memorandum. June 3, 1970." (That's how it appears in the bibliography of Dave Tompkins's book; the fact that it is an "IM" and the exact date should help the archivist track it down.)

Comment: @kimchi interesting find. David Kahn mentioned number 47 in The Code-Breakers (1973) on page 295. Could be a typo.

Comment: @Kimchi: another related question for me. Where did Claude Shannon do his groundbreaking work on the AT&T switchboard? My guess is it is that 463 West Street building. Ideas? It should be the biggest switchboard where tried his Information Theory, using switches for bites.

Comment: @Chuck I don't know, but assume West Street.

Comment: The UK's [Imperial War Museum](https://www.iwm.org.uk/history/churchills-top-secret-hotline-to-the-president)'s page has pictures, but claims the US end was in the basement of the Pentagon.

Comment: @JohnDallman The question is about the bad insecure "A3", not its good secure replacement, "SIGSALY", that the IWM's page describes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a photo in the article "Diplomacy in Scrambled Words" by Hal Borland appearing in the 22 September 1940 *Sunday New York Times Magazine*, pp. 5,15.  The picture is on p.5, and the caption reads "... an engineer adjusting scrambled sound tones". It shows a nerd hunched over a telephone equipment console.

The article states the location is in the "Overseas Control Room of the Telephone Building in New York", and gives no further street address.  But it was named in Cowan's
1930 article ["Transoceanic Telephone Service-Short-Wave Stations Planning and Construction of a Short-Wave Radio System"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5055548) as being [24 Walker Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32_Avenue_of_the_Americas).  (The 47 Walker Street address mentioned in the question is given by Kahn, who cites the 22 September 1940 NYT article, and a 8 October 1939 one, but neither NYT article gives a street address.  I suppose "47" is Kahn's mistake.)

Comment: @kichi: wow fantastic find. Very good photo. It shows a rather small machine that did the scramble. I just perused the Time Machine of the NYT and found more articles (without photos) about how the scramble worked, including a reference to Walker Street (no number). It is fascinating to see that the NYT commented without any hesitation on the machine at a time when the US was not yet at war and no censor was involved.